# Java library for polygons interesection

Tags: polygon, android

I have an Android app when I have multiple polygons of a person's position, and I want the intersection of these polygon to know his exact position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JTS](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html) is the gold-standard topology library for Java. The [Geometry](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry.html) class has a full set of methods for relating geometries, including [intersection](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry.html#intersects(com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry))).

Answer (score 1):

ESRI has a GIS [SDK](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/) on Android ..It has [samples](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/sample-code/geometry-sample/) on spatial relationships.